# Unit testing AngularJS and Flot Charts

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, flot, karma-runner

I am trying to unit test (Jasmine) AngularJS and Flot Charts but receive the following errors. I do not receive these errors in the console of my application and the charts render as expected.

> PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Mac OS X) Charts Directive should populate the container element FAILED
>       TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'placeholder.css("font-size").replace')
>           at parseOptions (/Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/flot/jquery.flot.js:740)
>           at Plot (/Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/flot/jquery.flot.js:673)
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/flot/jquery.flot.js:3059
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/directives/charts.js:6
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/angular.js:7942
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/test/unit/directives/charts.spec.js:10
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/test/unit/directives/charts.spec.js:23
>           at invoke (/Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/angular.js:2902)
>           at workFn (/Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/angular-mocks.js:1795)
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/angular-mocks.js:1782
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/test/unit/directives/charts.spec.js:24
>   PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Mac OS X): Executed 30 of 40 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.126 secs)
>
> Charts Directive:
>         FAILED  - should populate the container element   TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'placeholder.css("font-size").replace')
>           at parseOptions (/Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/flot/jquery.flot.js:740)
>           at Plot (/Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/flot/jquery.flot.js:673)
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/flot/jquery.flot.js:3059
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/directives/charts.js:6
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/angular.js:7942
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/test/unit/directives/charts.spec.js:10
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/test/unit/directives/charts.spec.js:23
>           at invoke (/Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/angular.js:2902)
>           at workFn (/Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/angular-mocks.js:1795)
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/app/js/libs/angular-mocks.js:1782
>           at /Library/WebServer/Documents/zui/test/unit/directives/charts.spec.js:24
>   PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Mac OS X): Executed 31 of 40 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.134 secs)

Directive:

```
angular.module('directives.FlotCharts', [])
    .directive('flotChart', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            controller: ['$scope', '$attrs', function ($scope, $attrs) {
                var plotid = '#' + $attrs.id,
                model = $scope[$attrs.ngModel];
                $scope.$watch('model', function (x) {
                    $.plot(plotid, x.data, x.options);
                });
            }]
        };
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('Charts', ['directives.FlotCharts'])
    .controller('diskChartCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.model = {};
        $scope.model.data = [
            {
                label: "Available",
                data: 20,
                color:"#00a34a"
            },
            {
                label: "Used",
                data: 100,
                color:"#c00"
            }
        ];

        $scope.model.options = {
            series: {
                pie: {
                    innerRadius: 0.5, // for donut
                    show: true,
                    label: {
                        formatter: function (label, series) {
                            return '<div class="pie">' + label + ': ' +
                                series.data[0][1] + 'GB <br>(' + Math.round(series.percent) + '%)</div>';
                            }
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            }
        };
    }])
}]);
```

Test Spec:

```
describe('Charts Directive', function () {
    var scope, html, tmpl, ctrl, $compile;

    var compileTmpl = function (markup, scope) {
        var el = $compile(markup)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        return el;
    };

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('directives.FlotCharts');
        module('Charts');
        inject(function ($rootScope, _$compile_, $controller) {
            $compile = _$compile_;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('diskChartCtrl', {$scope: scope});
            html = angular.element('<div data-flot-chart id="disk" data-chart="pie" data-status="danger" data-ng-model="model" data-ng-controller="diskChartCtrl"></div>');
            tmpl = compileTmpl(html, scope);
        });
    });

    it('should populate the container element', function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
        //expect(tmpl.html()).toContain('canvas');
    });
});
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue as commented by compiling the markup against rootScope and setting inline width and height styles. It may have been an issue of missing width and height properties.

```
inject(['$rootScope', '$compile', '$controller', function ($rootScope, $compile, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('itemChartCtrl', { $scope: scope });
    tmpl = '<div data-flot-chart id="items" data-chart="pie" data-status="danger" data-ng-model="model" data-ng-controller="itemChartCtrl" style="width:300px;height:300px"></div>';
    $compile(tmpl)($rootScope);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer to your question, but hopefully it will help steer you in the right direction.  Here's the source of the exception from `jquery.flot.js`:

```
fontDefaults = {
    style: placeholder.css("font-style"),
    size: Math.round(0.8 * (+placeholder.css("font-size").replace("px", "") || 13)),
    variant: placeholder.css("font-variant"),
    weight: placeholder.css("font-weight"),
    family: placeholder.css("font-family")
};
```

It appears that `placeholder.css('font-size')` is returning `undefined`.  I seem to remember hearing of some problems with `jQuery.css('margin')` not working in PhantomJS, but `jQuery.css('margin-left')` behaving correctly.

If you explicitly set `style: "font-size: 10px;"` on the element do you get different results?  I noticed you were setting the directive's class to `pie`, have you included any stylesheets?

Comment: I attempted to spoof the placeholder object without success. Through console logging I found that the `tmpl` object was undefined. This was remedied by manually compiling the html string and passing `$rootScope` as opposed to the "scope" scope.